# Refactor golang function - what type should be used?

Tags: go, kubernetes

Could anyone of you tell how to refactor the following functions, please?

I'd like to have one function eg. `getResource(name string, resourceType ????) []v1.?????`, but don't know what would be its return type.

```
func getPods(name string) []v1.Pod {
    pods, err := clientset.CoreV1().Pods(namespace).List(context.TODO(), getListOption(name))

    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    return pods.Items
}

func getServices(name string) []v1.Service {
    services, err := clientset.CoreV1().Services(namespace).List(context.TODO(), getListOption(name))

    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    return services.Items
}
```

Comment: There is no union in Go, interface can help, https://jordanorelli.com/post/32665860244/how-to-use-interfaces-in-go

Comment: Thank you, I will try this approach too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the invocation is nearly identical, and the content is nearly identical, they types are different.  [`CoreV1().Pods(namespace).List`](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/client-go@v0.22.3/kubernetes/typed/core/v1#PodInterface) is :

```golang
List(ctx context.Context, opts metav1.ListOptions) (*v1.PodList, error)
```

but [`CoreV1().Services(namespace).List`](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/client-go@v0.22.3/kubernetes/typed/core/v1#ServiceInterface) is

```golang
List(ctx context.Context, opts metav1.ListOptions) (*v1.ServiceList, error)
```

One returns a `*v1.PodList` and the other returns a `*v1.ServiceList`.  Both these distinct objects have `Items`, but one is a [`[]*Service`](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/api/core/v1#ServiceList) and the other is a [`[]*Pod`](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/api/core/v1#PodList).

I personally would think about not wrapping either.  I would call the underlying functions instead, using the same `CoreV1` client in both cases.
I certainly wouldn't try to combine them into one function.

If there's something to be combined here, it's namespace and name:

```
type ByName struct {
   Name string
   Namespace string
   v1 corev1.CoreV1Interface
}

func (b *ByName)Services(ctx context.Context) []v1.Service , error {
   return b.v1.Services(namespace).List(ctx,  getListOption(b.Name))
}

func (b *ByName)Pods(ctx context.Context) []v1.Pod, error {
  return b.v1.Pods(b.Namespace).List(ctx, getListOption(b.Name))
}
```

Now you don't have to pass name and namespace:

```
b := &ByName{
  Name: name,
  Namespace: namespace,
  v1: clientset.CoreV1(),
}

if svcs, err :=  b.Services(); err != nil {
   return nil, err
} else if pods, err := b.Pods(); err != nil {
  return nil, err
} else {
  ... continue processing
}
```

And you get the brevity you want without having to do a bunch of type checking.